# The new price does not appear

Tags: math, select, laravel-9, operation, discount

I have two tables: products (which has price_before and discount_id) and discounts (which has discount_value and discount_id) and I want to show the products with the new price.

This is my query in product controller:

```php
public function newPrice(Request $request)
    {
        $newPrice= Product::join('discounts','discounts.discount_id','=','products.discount_id')
        ->where('products.product_id',$request->id)
        ->select(DB::raw('products.*','(products.prict_before * discounts.discount_value/100) as priceAfter'))
        ->get();
        return response()->json($newPrice);
    }
```

and this is my route:

```php
Route::get('/newPrice/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@newPrice');
```

**My problem** is: when I test the query in postman, it shows me the information about the product without new price (priceAfter) and I want to return it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Is `products.prict_before` a typo?

Comment: It is correct,  it is a column in products table